# Format numbers in Pivottable usd 1000 separator by VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim SourceData As Range 
Worksheets("Report").Activate

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:CG890000"))
 
'Configure the pivot table

With pt
    .PivotFields("Outstanding Days").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Broker").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Local Currency").Orientation = xlRowField
End With

With pt
   .PivotFields("USD Value").Orientation = xlDataField
   .Function = xlSum
   .NumberFormat = "#,###"
   .Name = "USD Value"
End With
```

The error shows run-time error '438', object doesn't support this property or method at .Function = xlSum.
I saw someone wrote the similar code as me and it's working. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

the error shows run-time error '438', object doesn't support this property or method at  .Function = xlSum
I saw someone wrote the similar code as me and it's working. Can anyone help me to figure out what need to be changed here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you start a new `With` -block so often? Also, your code doesn't compile because currently it misses an `End With`. And you need to declare `pt`  and assign something before you can use it in  a `With`-block

Comment: Hi, I reduced my number of "with". I thought i declare pt in the beginning of my code: dim pt as Pivottable. Should I change anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are opening and closing far too much your `With`-statements. In top of that, at the end you seem to be missing one. I would propose something like:

```
'Configure the pivot table
With pt
    .PivotFields("Outstanding Days").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Broker").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Local Currency").Orientation = xlRowField
    With .PivotFields("USD Value")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "#,###"
        .Name = "USD Value"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your code, but .fuction =xlSum still showing issues (object doesn't support this property or method)